# How to change yaxes's title color for flot chart?

Tags: colors, flot, title, axes

I have a flot chart which has two titles: *CURRENT I11* and *CURRENT I12*. I wanna change the yaxes's title color. Is there a way to change yaxes title color?

```
yaxes: [{           min: 0,
                    max: 100,
                    tickSize: 5,
                    tickFormatter: function (v, axis) {
                        $(this).css("color", "#ff0000");
                        if (v % 10 == 0) {
                            return v + "A";
                        } else {
                            return ""; }},
                    axisLabel: "CURRENT I11",
                    //axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
                    axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
                    axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
                    axisLabelColor: '#EDC240',
                    axisLabelPadding: 6,
                    position: "left",
                    tickColor: '#bdbdbd',
                },
                {
                    min: 0,
                    max: 100,
                    tickSize: 5,
                    tickFormatter: function (v, axis) {
                        if (v % 10 == 0) {
                            return v + "A";
                        } else {
                            return "";
                        }
                    },
                    axisLabel: "CURRENT I12",
                    //axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
                    axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
                    axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
                    axisLabelPadding: 6,
                    position: "left",
                    color: '#AFD8F8',                        
                }
                    ]
```

I use *jquery.flot.axislabels.js*.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is almost correct - you need to:

- set the `axisLabelUseCanvas` property to `true` (just uncomment the
  lines you already have setting it to `true`)
- change the spelling of
  the `axisLabelColor` property to [`axisLabelColour`](https://github.com/markrcote/flot-axislabels#usage) (notice the
  different spelling of 'color')

A simplified example set of options looks like:

```
var options = {
    yaxes: [{
        axisLabel: "CURRENT I11",
        axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
        axisLabelColour: '#FF0000'
    }]
};
```

This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fvcwbbk8/1/) has a working example.